# Apple rejected the project because of using UIWebView in pod

Tags: ios, uiwebview

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

I got rejected mail from Apple for using above pods which have UIWebView. What would be the solution? What would be the updated pod for this problem?

Can we directly update the above pod?